# Conexão sendo recusada

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, restify

Seguindo este [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGuGdcwBzUZt10zvj6_xuDeasOnXdWWnx) do [Vedovelli](https://www.youtube.com/user/vedovelli) sobre node com restify e mysql, implementei no servidor com pm2.

Só que depois de alguns dias a conexão começou a ser recusada

Está mostrando essa mensagem:

```
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
code: 'ECNNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 3306,
fatal: true

PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro está dando nessa parte aqui, no arquivo [auth.js](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/restful_ws/blob/master/src/services/mysql/auth.js):

```
authenticate: (email, password) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const {connection, errorHandler} = deps
        const queryString = 'SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?'
        const queryData = [email, sha1(password)]
        connection.query(queryString, queryData, (error, results) => {
          if (error || !results.length) {
            errorHandler(error, 'Falha ao localizar o usuário', reject)
            return false
          }
          const {email, id} = results[0]
          const token = jwt.sign({email, id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 })
          resolve({token})
        })
      })
    }
```

Todo o meu projeto está [aqui](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/restful_ws) caso queiram olhar

O estranho que no localhost funciona

Comment: Qual o nome desse arquivo que você apresentou o código?

Comment: Na realidade olhando agora aqui o erro, a porta é a 3306, ou seja, seu servidor do `Node.js` não está conseguindo se conectar ao `MySQL`

Comment: É o arquivo [auth.js](https://github.com/cbcarlos07/restful_ws/blob/master/src/services/mysql/auth.js)

Comment: Consegue checar se a conexão com o `MySQL` está funcionando pelo `Workbench` nessa máquina?

Comment: Posso tentar, um momento

Comment: Sim consegue conectar

Comment: Mas veja bem, você está tentando conectar no endereço de ip `127.0.0.1`, pelo que entendi da sua resposta o endereço do servidor do `MySQL` é outro, estou errado?

Comment: Sim é outro. Está tudo configurado para o ip correto, mas ele mostra esse ai. Acho que deve ser porque é de onde está se originando, sei lá

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81102/discussion-between-adventistaam-and-sorack).

Comment: É fato de que o problema é que o `Node.js` não consegue conectar nesta porta do `MySQL`, mas a única coisa que eu posso te indicar é que você execute o comando `telnet localhost 3306` para comprovar isso. Como resolução mesmo não tenho muita idéia

Comment: Hum... como você falou, acho que a linha process.env.DB_HOST que vem do arquivo .env não está obtendo o host

Comment: Coloca um `console.log` no objeto que você usa no `mysql.createConnection` pra conferir isso

Comment: Eu dei um `console.log` no `process.env.DB_HOST` e deu `undefined`

Comment: Te chamei pra discussão no chat. Dá uma olhada lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como descrito na sua pergunta (pelo erro retornado) o seu servidor está tentando se conectar ao banco no `localhost`, verifique se o objeto com as configurações de conexão estão com as informações corretas na chamada da função `mysql.createConnection`.